# Python 3 - How do I return to first input after going a few if statements deep into code?

Tags: python

trying to get my code to return back to the first input asked after going through and answering all questions. The best way to explain it is through example code:

```
x = int(input("What number?: "))
if x == 1:
    y = str(input("What colour?: "))
    if y == "Red":
        print("ok")
        z = int(input("Do you wanna ask another num+colour? (1/0 is yes/no): "))
        if z == 1:
            #return to x (how do I do it?)
        elif z == 0:
            quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop, the `continue` and `break` statements:

- `while condition`:  In your case you can have an infinite loop `while True`, so it runs indefinitely until you reach a `break` statement, or finish the program.
- `continue`: It will ommit the remaining code and continue to the next iteration of the loop.
- `break`: Used to finish a loop. Only the loop, not the program.

  ```
  while True:
      x = int(input("What number?: "))
      if x == 1:
          y = str(input("What colour?: "))
          if y == "Red":
              print("ok")
              z = int(input("Do you wanna ask another num+colour? (1/0 is yes/no): "))
              if z == 1:
                  continue # to the next iteration
              elif z == 0:
                  break # finish loop
  ```